# Magento2 System Upgrade from 2.0.5 to 2.0.7 Check Component Dependency issue

Tags: magento2, magento2-dev-beta, magento-2.0.2, magento-2.0.4

I have started on upgrading the magento2.0.5 enterprise system to latest Magento2.0.7 from web interface.

Initially I faced the issues related cron setup, once I completed the cron setup all the errors were cleared, except Check Component Dependency issue.

**"Problem 1
- The requested package magento/product-enterprise-edition could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name."**
[image]

Please anyone can help me out!!

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like an issue with your `composer.json` in the root of your install.
Is your repo set properly?

Comment: Can you explain me on "Repo set properly", the only question I have is public key and private should be the same which we used for enterprise code download or it can be any valid public and private keys

Comment: public and private keys should be set in `https://marketplace.magento.com/customer/accessKeys/list/` - remember to login and then follow this link.

By repo set properly, you should see a few lines like this;

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
        }
    ],

Comment: Have you attempted this?

Comment: @ol'bobdole I did, what you told, still getting error. my error is : https://snag.gy/A1YoPD.jpg How can i solve this?

Comment: @zus Try deleting the contents of vendor (without deleting vendor itself) and running composer install. If that fails create a new question and link me.

Comment: @ol'bobdole Here my post https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/222817/57334

Comment: @ol'bobdole If i delete contents of vendor (without deleting vendor itself) my erro like : : Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory.